# Problems configuring app for Push Notifications

Tags: ios5, push-notification

I am trying to setup push notifications in an app I'm building.  I've followed the tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 but I'm not successful.

I've created the CSR, App Id and SSL Certificate necessary to setup the developer push notifications.  When I run the commend line openssl, I can connect successfully (according to the tutorial).

I believe I'm picking the right code signing profile in xcode.  I select the iPhone Developer under the profiles that matches my bundle identifier but the developer looks the same.  You can see a screenshot at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28kuM.jpg

When I try and run my app, on my phone; not in the simulator, I get the following in the xcode output window:

```
   2012-09-11 14:47:35.907 (M+B)2B[2110:707] Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x3e61d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

I figure it must have something to do with my provisioning profile but I can't figure out what.  I've been through the steps of the first part of the tutorial but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

My app requires iOS 5.0 and I'm using XCode 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you re-issued the mobileprovision you are signing the app with after having configured the app ID for push notifications?

When opening the mobileprovision file with the text editor you should be able to see the `<key>aps-environment</key>` line in there, otherwise try re-issuing the mobileprovision in the  iOS developer portal.

Comment: This partially solved my problem.  I thought I had re-issued the ad hoc distribution provisioning profile but it still wasn't working.  On another website I found a suggestion to delete the xcuserdata folder from the .xcodeproj archive.  I did that then I re-issued the provisioning profile again.  After that I was able to successfully register the device for push notifications.